# Where is the Schatten norm differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Let $M_n$ be the space of real $n \times n$ matrices, and let $|\cdot|_p$ be the $p$-[Schatten norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) on $M_n$, for $p \neq 2$. For $A \in M_n$, $|A|_p=\big(\sum \sigma_i^p(A)\big)^{1/p}$, where $\sigma_i(A)$ are the singular values of $A$.

> Is $| \cdot |_p$ differentiable at any non-zero point $A \in M_n$? Is it smooth there? If not, at which points is it differentiable?

I *think* that $| \cdot |_p$ is $C^{\infty}$ when restricted to $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, since  $|A|_p^p=\text{tr}(|A|^p)$: The map $A \to |A|$ is smooth on $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, I guess that the map $A \to A^p$ is smooth on the domain of symmetric matrices. (Is it really? I am not sure).

Comment: Let $\lambda:\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}\to\mathbb{R}^N$ be the singular value mapping and let 
 $\phi:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ be whatever you're doing to the singular values. Then as a rule of thumb, $\phi\circ \lambda$ will only be smooth at $X$ when $\phi$ is smooth and $X$ has no repeated singular values.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be a $n\times n$ (real) symmetric matrix.
Then $B \mapsto \lambda_i(B), \ \forall i$ is
smooth on the region where $B$ has simple spectrum (no repeated eigenvalues).
See "4. Eigenvalue deformation" in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/

Now, we have $\|A\|_p = (\mathrm{Tr}((A^\mathsf{T}A)^{p/2}))^{1/p}$.
So, $\|A\|_p$ is smooth on the region where $A^\mathsf{T}A$ has simple spectrum (no repeated eigenvalues).

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that the Schatten norm will be non-differentiable at all points with repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: @AsafShachar  I am not sure about it.